# Tensor contraction exercsie

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I am working on a "tensor gymnastics" exercise, and have arrived at the following line to simplify:

$\delta_{ik} y^{i} X_{ij}$

where $\delta_{ik}$ is the Kroenecker delta. Does this simplify to:

$y^{k} X_{kj}$, i.e., replace *all* of the $i's$ with $k's$, or just apply to one of the $y^i$ or $X_{ij}$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Contracted indices generally should only ever appear twice in an expression. It's likely that you've made a mistake earlier on that's let to this ill-formed expression.